# C# COM Add In failing while calling from thread

Tags: c#, excel, com, user-defined-functions

I am in process of writing UDF library for Excel  in C#. I will have long running UDF so I want to make my UDF asynchronous so that Excel UI will stays usable while calling UDF. Below is my code; but it fails while calling Excel from spawned thread...

```
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
[ComVisible(true)]
[ComDefaultInterface(typeof(IRAPDataAddIn))]
public class RAPDataAddIn : IRAPDataAddIn
{

    public string GetPositionData(Excel.Range Portfolios, Excel.Range Security)
    {





        Excel.Application excelApp = (Excel.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");

        Excel.Range target = (Excel.Range)excelApp.get_Caller(System.Type.Missing);


        Thread _workerThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(this.GetData));
        _workerThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
        _workerThread.CurrentUICulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture;

        _workerThread.Start(target);

        return "Getting Data";
    }


    public void GetData(object Range)
    {
        Excel.Range target = Range as Excel.Range;

        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        object[,] returnData = new object[2,2];

        returnData[0, 0] = " FirstThread";       
        returnData[0, 1] = " SecondThread"; 
        returnData[1, 0] = " ThirdThread";              
        returnData[1, 1] = " FourthThread";  

        var Start = (Excel.Range)target.Worksheet.Cells[1,1];
        var End = (Excel.Range)target.Worksheet.Cells[2,2];

        Excel.Range r = (Excel.Range)target.Worksheet.Range[Start, End];

        try
        {
            r.Value2 = returnData; ***//It fails here***
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: "It fails" is not an appropriate diagnostic.  There's no point in forcing us to guess at something you *know*, the exception message and stack trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Disclaimer: I develop the Excel-DNA library)*

I suggest you implement your Excel UDF using the (free) [Excel-DNA](http://exceldna.codeplex.com) library. I have recently added some experimental support for asynchronous functions, so now would be a good time to try it out. I put an initial outline of the current asynchronous function support here: http://exceldna.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Asynchronous%20Functions&referringTitle=Documentation. The best place for support on Excel-DNA is the [Excel-DNA Google group](http://groups.google.com/group/exceldna).

There are a few potential problems with your approach:

- The Application object you retrieve with `Marshal.GetActiveObject` might not be the Excel instance you are running under. If more that one Excel instance has been started, it will be the most recent Excel started.
- You can't just pass the 'Range' COM object to another thread - it is an STA apartment-bound object, so can't be used from a thread that is not the main Excel thread without explicit cross-thread marshaling.
- Any of your COM calls from the other thread into Excel may fail if Excel is 'busy, for example if Excel is busy calculating, or the user is editing a cell, or even just has the mouse button down. So every COM call needs to deal with possible exceptions as part of the normal operation.

There are a few ways to implement this kind of work with Excel-DNA, so you should have a look at the library and post to the Google group if you need more specific guidance.

Comment: Hi Govert; after you recommendation I have started using ExcelDna... I will have long running UDF which will collect data from different servers and give it back to excel clients. So, I am able to paste data to desired locations asynchronously by maintaining ExcelReference (i.e. to cell from where function was invoked); but I also want to retain the original formula in the cell. How can I do this ?

Comment: It sounds like you need to ave a look at the new Reactive Extensions support in Excel-DNA. That will allow you to push data into cells asynchronously quite easily. Check here: http://exceldna.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Reactive%20Extensions%20for%20Excel and ask on the Google group here: http://groups.google.com/group/exceldna